# Methods in a Sequence Diagram

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram

I am creating this sequence diagram, and wondered exactly what methods to include. I have included all methods in every method, for example, the

```
handleCustomerAccountAction()
```

method, got a method from another class called 
`getListOfCustomers()`

Is that right to do, or do you only have to include the method and not all the methods it uses inside it?

Also, is it okay to show the same method multiple times on other methods? For example the method

```
getListOfCustomers()
```

is shown three times (the one with a loop around it), but from different methods.

Here is the image of my sequence diagram:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It always depends on what you want to show. A SD shows a certain collaboration you want to explain in detail. A SD should focus on a certain aspect and must not show each and every message (e.g. certain call branches can simply be left out). However, if a method is called twice in a sequence you must show it if it's of importance.

Comment: Thank you for the answer